# proof for $[\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})]\vec{a}=(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})$

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

I encounter this triple product property in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)
But I can't find proof for 
$$[\vec{a}\cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})]\vec{a}=(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})$$
The RHS cross product produce vector while the LHS produce scalar.
So this got me stumble on working out this equation.
How do I get scalar equals to vector?
Does anyone know proof for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what "The RHS cross product produce vector while the LHS produce dot product" means.  Both sides of the equation are in fact vectors.

Comment: Sorry,edited the text.Btw,I though dot product with vector always result in scalar.

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is a scalar.  However you are taking the scalar $a \cdot (b \times c)$ and multiplying the vector $a$ by this scalar.

Comment: sorry, you are correct.I overlooked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All quantities below are vectors.  I will use the following properties of cross-products and dot-products:

$$
(x \times y) \times z = (x \cdot z) y - (y \cdot z)x
\\
x \cdot ( y \times z) = y \cdot (z \times x) = z \cdot (x \times y)
\\
x \cdot (x \times y) = 0
$$

We start with the righthand side.  For convenience, denote $a \times c = v$.  Then

\begin{align}
(a \times b) \times (a \times c) = (a \times b) \times v &= (a \cdot v)b - 
(b \cdot v) a
\\
&= (a \cdot(a \times c) )b - (b \cdot(a \times c)) a
\\
&= 0 - (- a \cdot (b \times c))a
\\
&= (a \cdot (b \times c) )a
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for the workout.I had some geometry intuition after your initial commend but my vector algebra is sill elementary, difficulty piecing vector properties.